# To copy a mongo Collection into a relevant java object

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a java code where I need to refer to a mongo collection pretty frequently, which is taking a lot of time. I don't have any issue with having big objects in the heap. So, basically I want to copy all of that collection to a relevant object into java which I can refer to while searching for fields.

1) Is it possible to copy all the documents in that collection into a JsonArray/List at one go without iterating through the documents?

2) Can I do aggregate searches on a JSONArray to find the relevant docs like we make queries and then do a find operation?

Answer (score 0):

1) Is it possible to copy all the documents in that collection into a JsonArray/List at one go without iterating through the documents?

A: 
If you want to find all the documents of JavaDocumentName(any collection name in java)

```
List<JavaDocumentName> listRes = mongoOperation.findAll(JavaDocumentName.class);
```

2) Can I do aggregate searches on a JSONArray to find the relevant docs like we make queries and then do a find operation?

```
Query searchQuery = new Query(Criteria.where("name").is("Parth"));
List<JavaDocumentName> listRes = mongoOperations.find(searchQuery, JavaDocumentName.class);
```

Example:

@Document(collection = "Customer")
public class Customer{

}

List listRes = mongoOperation.findAll(Customer.class);

If you want JSON then controller method will produce JSON for you at the end as given below,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customers", method = RequestMethod.GETG,
  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
 public Customer getCustomer{

 }
```

============================

One more way to do it

You can use a CollectionCallback to deal with the returned DBObject directly and simply toString() it:

```
template.execute("jvmInfo", new CollectionCallback<String>() {
  String doInCollection(DBCollection collection) {
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query)
   return cursor.next().toString()
 }
 } 
 String result = mongoTemplate.findOne(basicQuery, String.class, "jvmInfo");
```

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get it. By "JavaDocumentName", do you mean the actual collection in the db or the jsonarray in which all the data is copied? Further, can you give me a snippet of how to copy the database collection into the jsonArray? Also, once I have the array ready, I want to do all the queries on the array itself.

Comment: @Document(collection = "Customer")
public class Customer{

}

List<Customer> listRes = mongoOperation.findAll(Customer.class);

Comment: Can't I just store it into a JSON array, instead of creating a custom class?

Comment: At the end, you will get JSON array itself when this method is called from client- postman or any frontend client.                                  @RequestMapping(value = "/customers", method = RequestMethod.GETG,
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
  public Customer getCustomer{
  
  }